# Performance Issues entity framework with query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am currently working on this query in EF 6.

```
using (var metadata = new DMSEntities())
{
    var q = from row in metadata.db_Patient orderby row.Name
                    where !row.isDeleted where row.FileLocation.StartsWith(SearchTerm)
                    || row.Name.StartsWith(SearchTerm)
                    || row.Surname.StartsWith(SearchTerm)
                    || row.IDNumber.StartsWith(SearchTerm)
                    || row.Initials.StartsWith(SearchTerm)
                    select new bl_Patient
                    {
                        Name = row.Surname,
                        Surname = row.Name,
                        IDNumber = row.IDNumber,
                        Initials = row.Initials,
                        Location = row.FileLocation,
                        patientID = row.patientID
                    };

    var FCount = q.FutureCount();

    var Results = q.Skip(Paging.Skip).Take(Paging.Take).Future();

    var Count = FCount.Value;
    var TotalPages = Count / 10;

    if (TotalPages!= 0 && Count % TotalPages != 0)
    {
        TotalPages = TotalPages+1;
    }

    Paging.TotalPages = TotalPages;

    return Results.ToList();
}
```

Is there anyway to increase performance. I do not have access to sql studio so creating views or stored procedures will not work. On my test machine, everything works fine however on the clients much slower laptop it hangs on first load. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I see my question has been set on hold so let me see if I can clear up some things.

First of all this is a windows forms application I created to help out one of my friends. Database and application is ran from a single machine. I use SQL server. There was no requirements agreed on by me or client as it was just done as a favor. The laptop has a dual core 2.4ghz and 4 gb of ram and is about 4 years old. I asked the question because I wanted to know if there is any other tips that can be given. I have explained to the client that there is no real way to improve performance as the real problem is the laptop. We have found ways around the Issue and the client can use the application now. Also just so you guys know I only have about a year and half development experience so I asked this question more to increase my own skill then solving the actual issue.

More information regarding what I have changed.

I have implemented a 3 letter minimum on the search items. This has mostly solved the Issue.

I also added some indexing as a have never really done this before and had to go read up on this.

The database has about 4000+ items, it does still hang sometimes however it is now less prone to crashing and completely usable.

For the background of the app it is simply to manage Patients and the location of there folders. I only posted this one query as this was the only one giving issues. There is no other list methods.

Comment: You want an answer based on only one query? What about some information about the application and the architecture. Does it all run on one machine? Is it even realistic to expect it will run on the client machine? Which minimum hardware requirements did you agree on with the customer? What about indexes? Size of the table/database?

Comment: @GertArnold I apologise for the vague question, I have tried to improve it and will take more care in the future.

Comment: OK, that's good. I think reopening the question isn't very useful anymore because it has an accepted answer and at the moment there doesn't seem to be a direct problem anymore. At least you've improved your skills to ask a question at Stack Overflow question, which isn't unimportant either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table scan. Not a lot you can do.

You look for a string that starts with the input - that is good, that is sargeable, that an index can help with.

But you do so in 5 fields. Let's hope they all each have an index (or are part of an index where they come FIRST). But even then - check the SQL and query plan, there isa chance SQL Server says "ok, I rather do a table scan". And there you go.

You also count the results (q.FutureCount();) - which means SQL Server has to do the query AGAIN (2 times) - but this time for the whole table.

Speed ups:

- Kill the future query. If you really need it, issue it on a SECOND CONNECTION (so it can happen in parallel) but definitely only once (store the result).
- Check the SQL generated, the indices and the query plan. Forget the EF side for that type of question - it all resolves around the SQL. I am not saying "do not use EF" - I say to find the error look at the SQL, query plans, not the EF level code.
- Make sure to set the proper tx isolation. ReadCommited for both queries. Particularly if you run the 2 statements in parallel. This can / has to be set in the connection string.

Comment: Thank you very much I read up on some of the items. I have edit my question. I have used some of your tips and will be reading up on more of your solutions. I am still a Junior developer and was looking for answers exactly like your to point me in a a direction to research.